# VPAID Impressions firing, but not VAST Impression?

Tags: html5-video, ads, vast

Just wondering if anyone has heard/witnessed this behavior:

I have a VAST with a VPAID MediaFile. When loaded by players, I'm expecting the VAST Impression URL to fire if there was not an error, have the VPAID file loaded, and have it fire a separate "impression", e.g. creativeView.

Has anyone noticed scenarios in which your VAST impression URI doesn't fire but the VPAID runs and fires all necessary events, specifically creativeView/impression?

Comment: Do you have a URL to the VAST response? I don't mind taking a quick look...

Comment: @OliC it's a little difficult to explain, but this isn't happening with a VAST I have.. Just theoretically I was wondering if this can happen

Comment: In the big of video  players,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once initAd is called, the VPAID creative needs to fetch an ad and bring it back to the player, at which point, if it successfully gets an ad, the impression *should* fire (just as the AdStarted event is fired).

However, in the real world, this is not always the case- there are certainly things that may prevent the Url from being hit, such as the creative loading within a secure iframe and the urls not firing because they are http...
There are also a lot of players that claim 'VPAID compliancy', that in my experience don't always behave how you would expect!

Comment: I think it has to do with the final part of your comment-- i.e. the player claims it's vpaid compliant but it doesn't seem to be

Comment: Yes, quite likely...Which player are you testing with?

Comment: A few different ones, but this issue is on ooyala

Comment: Ah- yes that is probably the issue then...I would test on JW, as they have a decent test tag and along with Kaltura, they seem to be the most VPAID compliant player out there at the mo'!
Test page: http://demo.jwplayer.com/ad-tester/